# Regular expressions under Microsoft

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to know a very simple thing: does a string end with a backslash yes or no?

```
string bla = @"C:\";
if ( ! Regex.IsMatch(bla, "\b$")) { bla = bla + @"\"; }
```

But it's not working. I want to add a slash if there's no slash at the end of the string. I tried several ways, even if I just try to match a backslash, without having it to be at the end of the string, its a huge problem:

```
Regex.IsMatch(bla, "\b") // Not working
Regex.IsMatch(bla, @"\") // Giving me and exception even!
Regex.IsMatch(bla, @"\\$") // not working
```

I'm out of options. How the .... can I match a backslash with C#?

Comment: You need to use two backslashes (if you are using @). Since the backslash character is a special character you need to escape it

Comment: I tried that too, not working... Nothing works. Microsoft sais I can use \b and that doesn't work either.

Comment: If you are working with paths, looking at [System.IO.Path](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path(v=vs.110).aspx) might help you.

Comment: Regex.IsMatch(bla, @"\\$") is the correct solution, it detects if a string ends with an \

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I want to know a very simple thing: does a string end with a backslash
>   yes or no.

Then you don't need regex...

```
string str = "your string here";
str.EndsWith(@"\"); // true or false
```

If you really want to do it the regex way though, you just have to make sure your regex is correct. This should work:

```
.*\\$

.* will match any optional leading characters
\\ will match the '\' and has been escaped with another '\'
$ will match until the end of your string.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! Finally this works. However, I'm still very curious why Regex is not working on such a simple task.

Comment: See my updated comment. There's no way your regexes would work, because it's literally searching for a string that only contains a backslash and nothing else. That's just invalid, in every programming language. There are other characters in your string, so your regex should handle those as well (in case of my regex: ignoring them).

Comment: Yeah I tried that too, starting with .* even though I didn't use "^", but that also didn't work. Well I guess I'll forget about Regex and try to avoid it during this project. I'm very happy with your EndsWith option.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish if I may ask? Always try the simplest option. For simple strings you should generally use the string functions instead of regex, but I get a feeling that you're working with file/folder paths, which is where System.IO comes in (as Filburt suggested). That would make things a lot easier for you.

Comment: I'm working with paths, however, as plain strings. The app is talking to a remote unix server so the paths are plain strings as soon as they reach my C# app. Also the paths have nothing to do with the local filesystem, it's all remote stuff.

Comment: Check out System.IO.Path, it might help you and make things easier: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path(v=vs.110).aspx.

Comment: @Saskia `Path.Combine` allows you to concat strings to a path string without worrying about path separators: `Path.Combine("C:\\foo", "bar", "baz")` will work just as `Path.Combine(@"C:\foo\", "bar", "baz")` so can skip testing for trailing slashes.

Comment: Cool, thanks guys, I'm looking at your link and other options now. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Yours code doesn't work becuase static method `Regex.IsMatch` has two parameters..

```
public static bool IsMatch(string input, string pattern)
{
    return new Regex(pattern).IsMatch(input);
}
```

So you should give a try with:

```
if (!Regex.IsMatch(bla, @".*\\$"))
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo, of course I entered two options, it wouldn't compile otherwise. I'll update the question just in case. Anyway, your example also didn't work, I tried a million things. I will try to avoid regex completely under Microsoft, it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: `@"C:\"` is `"C:\\"`
`@".*\$"` is incorrect as the last character to parseRegex is missing
`@".*\\"` is correct as it will be translated to look for string with two `"\"` at the end - this is tricky, double chars encoding, one for C# string, and another for a Regex string.

Comment: Just out of curiousity, I tried what you suggested, but it didn't match. Also it makes no sense it's matching from the beginning of the string if you don't specify "^".

Comment: What is your test case? I tried my code with var bla = @"C:\"  and it gives me true for the Regex check. Adding "^" at the beginning will force matching whole string.

Comment: Well, then I must have a rotten installation or something, cause over here string bla = @"C:\"; and if (Regex.IsMatch(bla, @"\\$")) is not returning true. Also including .* even though I didn't say "^" doesn't match. \b also doesn't match. Everything in Visual Studio works well, except regular expressions.